# Verifying a change of variables

Tags: partial-differential-equations, solution-verification, change-of-variable, weak-derivatives

I have a non-trivial weak solution $u_0 \in H^1(\mathbb{R}^N)$ for the following problem:

$$\begin{align*}
(P_1) \begin{cases}
-\Delta u + u &= \lambda f(u) \ \text{in} \ \mathbb{R}^N,\\
&u \in H^1(\mathbb{R}^N),
\end{cases}
\end{align*}$$

$\lambda > 0$

and I would like to show that $w(x) := u_0 \left( \frac{x}{t} \right)$, with $t > 0$, is a non-trivial weak solution for the problem:

$$\begin{align*}
(P_2) \begin{cases}
-\Delta u + u &= f(u) \ \text{in} \ \mathbb{R}^N,\\
&u \in H^1(\mathbb{R}^N),
\end{cases}
\end{align*}$$

I would like to know if my computation below is correct.

Let $y := \frac{x}{t}$.

$$\begin{align*}
\int_{\mathbb{R}^N} \nabla w(x) \nabla v(x) dx &= \int_{\mathbb{R}^N} \nabla u_0 \left( \frac{x}{t} \right) \nabla v(x) dx\\
&= \int_{\mathbb{R}^N} \nabla u_0(y) \nabla v(ty) t^N dy\\
&= \int_{\mathbb{R}^N} \nabla u_0(y) t \nabla v(ty) t^N dy\\
&= t^{N+1} \int_{\mathbb{R}^N} \nabla u_0(y) \nabla v(ty) dy\\
&= t^{N+1} \lambda \int_{\mathbb{R}^N} f(u_0(y)) v(ty) dy\\
&= t^{N+1} \lambda \int_{\mathbb{R}^N} f \left( u_0 \left( \frac{x}{t} \right) \right) v(x) \frac{1}{t^N} dx\\
&= t \lambda \int_{\mathbb{R}^N} f(w(x)) v(x) dx, \forall v \in H^1(\mathbb{R}^N).
\end{align*}$$

If $t = \frac{1}{\lambda}$, then $w$ is a non-trivial weak solution for $(P_2)$.

Thanks in advance!